# Is there a way to write WinRT apps in Windows7 & VS2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, windows-runtime

Is there a way to write WinRT apps in Windows7 & VS2010? Some SDK to download?

I'm particularly interested in networking stuff (Windows.Networking.Socktes)

Or do I need to use Windows 8 developer preview?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there is a way to do it on Windows 7 I haven't seen it.

You can download VS 11 (with Fx 4.5) but it does not have any RT stuff.

So yes, the Win 8 preview seems to be the only route at this moment. Do get the largest download.

Comment: AfaIct there are no `Windows.*` namespaces or assemblies available.

Comment: In WinRT, there is. Different namespace tree, mostly the same classes.

Answer (score 0):

It's only possible to do some preprocessing (C preprocessing, flex/yacc, T4) in VS 2010 and then use the generated code in Visual Studio 11. It makes sense until Visual Studio 11 becomes more stable.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 release preview runs under VMWare under Windows 7 just fine.