# Windows 8 sdk on visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, windows-8, windows-runtime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to write WinRT apps in Windows7 & VS2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865892/is-there-a-way-to-write-winrt-apps-in-windows7-vs2010)

Is it possible to somehow develop windows 8 apps (metro style app) on visual studio 2010 and windows 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.

Comment: [citation needed]