# Is it possible to build WinRT applications on Windows 7?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7, windows-runtime

Using Visual Studio 11 is it possible to build WinRT applications on Windows 7?

Comment: Bonus question, can we do it using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen that question has already been asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865892/is-there-a-way-to-write-winrt-apps-in-windows7-vs2010

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No; WinRT is only available on Windows 8 and AFAIK there have been no announcements that they will be made available in Win7.  At BUILD, they specifically said that WinRT was only to be supported on Win8.  By extension, you won't be able to develop against WinRT on a Win7 machine because the support just won't be made available.

Comment: WinRT is the Windows8 way of interacting with the Windows8 Metro screen and providing apps via Windows8 appstore. Neither of these are available in previous editions of Windows, and consequently WinRT is not (and will never) be made available by Microsoft to previous editions of Windows