# Can you write normal Windows applications with C++/CX?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime

Or are you restricted to the "Metro-style" applications and Windows Store apps?

At first, I thought C++/CX would be a good alternative to C++/CLI as it has some nifty C#-esque keywords ('sealed', 'partial') and it also compiles to native code, rather than using .NET. But reading online, all I can find is information regarding Windows Store apps and Metro-styled applications...

Also, is WinRT for Windows 8 and above only?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can write desktop apps in C++/Cx and can use some Windows Runtime API (those marked in the documentation and headers as available for desktop apps) in desktop apps. See [Windows Runtime APIs for desktop apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn554295(v=vs.85).aspx). The [Enumerate app packages sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Package-Manager-Inventory-ee821079) on MSDN demonstrates using C++/Cx to call Windows Runtime API in a desktop app.

The Windows Runtime Xaml classes are not available to desktop apps, but since you can mix-and-match C++ and C++/Cx you can call typical desktop UI API (Win32, MFC, DirectX, etc.) from an app which also uses C++/Cx.

C++/Cx isn't really an alternative to C++/CLI. Other than using some similar syntax they have quite different goals. As you note, C++/Cx is not a managed language and so it cannot be used to call managed code. The primary reason to choose C++/CLI is for interop with managed code. C++/Cx is a good option if you need to call into the Windows Runtime from your desktop app.

The Windows Runtime is available only on Windows 8 and later.

Comment: The  "Enumerate app packages sample" doesn't compile in VS2017. So it's not a super helpful part of the answer. But it is interesting.

Answer (score -3):

the first line on the wikipedia page for [C++/CX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CX) is

> C++/CX (component extensions) is a language extension for C++ compilers from Microsoft that enables **C++ programmers to write programs for the new Windows Runtime platform, or WinRT**. *(emphasis added)*

So it appears that C++/CX is to WinRT as C++/CLI is to .Net/CLR. I.e C++/CX is for writing windows Apps with WinRT. WinRT is for windows 8 store and metro apps.

You can write regular windows API apps in C++, so you might be able to do the same in C++/CX. But it may not be easy or possible, but since the extensions are specific to WinRT, why would you want to. C++/CLI compiles to CLR bytecode, to be run with the common language runtime. Getting C++/CX to generate an executable that doesn't depend on WinRT, is the crux of the issue.

This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574907/is-it-possible-to-build-winrt-applications-on-windows-7) post indicates that yes WinRT is only for Windows 8. (Presumably Windows 10 as well.)

Comment: "...so you might be able to" doesn't really answer my question. Thanks for the (emphasized) Wikipedia quote but that wasn't one of my questions either. I know C++/CX is geared towards WinRT.

Comment: @NoahRoth I don't know how difficult or possible it is to get the MS C++/CX compiler to generate an executable that doesn't depend on WinRT, If you can then your answer is yes. I have edited the answer to clarify that. Unless by "normal app" you meant a WinRT Desktop app, in that case my answer is probably irrelevant; I assumed "normal" app meant windows program using WinAPI; WinAPI is the basic API that is included, and extended, with every version of windows.

Comment: This answer is unbelievably vague, and wrong when it tries to be specific. You can **easily** consume Windows Runtime components in a Windows Desktop application. It's just COM after all, that can be used through C++/CX language extensions, WRL code, or even plain C or C++ code.

Comment: Iinspectable's answer is right, Windows Runtime is base on COM, view this course to read more detail, https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/windows-runtime-essentials